# Display query result with formik

Tags: react-native, formik

I'm doing my first tests with react native and I have a question. I am making a file to see a client, and I need to fill in the fields that already exist with the data that I bring. I already have the api call made and it returns the data (I show the data I receive below) but I can't show it. The code that I receive with the call (and that I get from the console.log) is the following:

```
LA RESPUESTA ES {"address":[{"id":"11","cif":"B123456","nombre":"Cliente de prueba 1","direccion":"C/ Pruebas n 3","cp":"18000","poblacion":"Granada","provincia":"Granada","telefono":"34666777888","email":"pruebas@pruebas.es"}]}
```

I have tried to do it for example: response.address.cif and it doesn't work (It says undefined) However, if I call response.address it tells me that it is an object. My code:

```
     useEffect(() => {
          ( async () => {
              if(params?.idAddress){
                  const response = await getDatoscliente(auth, params.idAddress);
                  const strtest = JSON.stringify(response);
                  console.log("LA RESPUESTA ES "+strtest);
                  await formik.setFieldValue("cif", address.cif);
              }
          })()
          },[params])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. The only problem is that the response is an array with a single element, so I had to call it telling it the position number I wanted. This is how it has been solved (In case it helps someone):

```
await formik.setFieldValue("cif", response.address[0].cif);
```